# Azure OMS - Heartbeat Test - If the server is down for more than a day, no alerts will be generated

Tags: azure, monitoring, health-monitoring

There is an issue with the current Heartbeat query we are using. The query works perfectly, however I have observed an issue while setting up the alert.

Breakdown of the query:

```
       Type=Heartbeat Computer in $ComputerGroups[NON-PROD_Group] | 
       measure max(TimeGenerated) as LastCall by Computer | where LastCall < NOW-5MINUTE
```

Query checks for Heartbeat of computer in the group ‘**NON-PROD_Group**’
Measure **max**(TimeGenerated) as **LastCall** by Computer: will check for the time of last occurrence of Heartbeat from all the server and assign the value to a variable ‘LastCall’. ‘LastCall’ now has the time of last heartbeat

Where **LastCall** < **NOW-5MINUTES**: this section will check if the last heartbeat was before 5 minutes from ‘NOW’. Alert is triggered based on that.

I have given TIME WINDOW as 24 hour. The issue here is alert is generated for all the occurrences between ‘**NOW-5MINUTES**’ and 24 HOURS. There are no alerts generated if the LastCall falls outside the time window.
**If the server is down for more than a day, no alerts will be generated.**

**For Instance, if Friday evening One of the server goes down, alert notifications will come in until Saturday evening(24 Hours is maximum time allowed) after that the alert clears and no more notifications are generated.** 
Monday morning, the alert would be cleared and will report everything is working fine.

Comment: you got any solution this problem yet!! m facing the same out here.

Comment: not yet. for time being I have created one more new alert just to monitor it on weekends. :)

Answer (score 0):

Heartbeat
| summarize LastHeartbeat=max(TimeGenerated) by Computer, OSType, ResourceGroup, Resource, ResourceProvider, ResourceType
| where LastHeartbeat < ago(5m)
// If you are looking for any specific resource group, you may add in where condition like ResourceGroup == 'ecom'